# Updating .git with newly created remote branch

Tags: git, git-branch

Context:

- working on branch A
- branch B has been created remotely and being updated
- `git branch -a` does not show branch B

How can branch B be checked out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
git fetch --all # Fetch all remote branches
git checkout B
```